# How to block randomized HTML tag names in ad-blocker?

Tags: adblock, ublock-origin, ublock

How to block ads which appear in randomized HTML tags using ad-blockers, i.e. ABP (AdBlockPlus) or uBO (uBlock Origin)?

Example:

```
<U-RLCE class="uqRMKJfSUjw ">
    <U-RLCE class="uqRMMP7abhRgO7Q">
        <a class="c-link" href="/promo">ADVETISEMENT</a>
    </U-RLCE>
    <U-RLCE class="c-header">ADS</U-RLCE>
    <U-RLCE class="uqRMMP7aEigk">
        <U-RLCE class="uqRMMP7aEigk__i ">
            <U-RLCE id="uq1oOJuOo1U5TsJr71opDanxw4ZSMhQ" ></U-RLCE>
            <script>...</script>
        </U-RLCE>
    </U-RLCE>
</U-RLCE>
```

Note that the tag name `<U-RLCE>` is also auto-generated random name along with `id` and `class` names.

Answer (score 0):

You need a user script, which can be run with
[Greasemonkey](https://addons.mozilla.org/firefox/addon/greasemonkey/) (Firefox),
[Tampermonkey](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/tampermonkey/dhdgffkkebhmkfjojejmpbldmpobfkfo) (Chrome)
and
[Violent Monkey](https://addons.opera.com/en/extensions/details/violent-monkey/) (Opera).

Below is a sample such script. Note that I have not tested this script :

```
// ==UserScript==
// @nameElement Remover
// @namespace   http://forums.mozillazine.org/memberlist.php?mode=viewprofile&u=261941
// @description Gets rid of U-RLCE ads
// @author  your-name-here
// @include *
// @version 1.0
// @grant   none
// @license http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0/
// ==/UserScript==

ads = document.getElementsByTagName("U-RLCE");
if (ads.length > 0) {
  for (i = 0, j = ads.length; i < j; i++) {
    ads[i].parentNode.removeChild(ads[i]);
  }
}
```

To use :

1. Paste the above in a text editor like Notepad
2. Change the URL in the `@include` clause to match the site you want to modify,
   or leave it as it is which will work for all websites
3. Save the file as `your-name-here.user.js` to the desktop
4. With the appropriate extension installed and enabled in your browser, drag and drop the file onto the browser window
5. Follow on-screen instructions to install the script.

Comment: This script will only detect elements named "U-RLCE" which the original poster indicated is ALSO randomized. Hence, this script is useless. Try again.